# Create A FIX Message using Quickfix Python

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am a very new user to Quickfix Python. I want to send a QuoteRequest. My function to create a new quote request message is as below:

```
import quickfix as fix

def create_quote_request():
    message = fix.Message()
    header  = message.getHeader()
    header.setField(fix.MsgType(fix.MsgType_QuoteRequest))
    gp      = fix.Group()
    gp.setField(fix.Symbol("GBPUSD"))
    gp.setField(fix.Side(fix.Side_BUY))
    gp.setField(fix.Account("TestAcc"))
    gp.setField(fix.Currency("GBP"))
    message.addGroup(gp)
    fix.Session.sendToTarget(message, self.sessionID)
```

When I execute the code, I am getting error as below:

> NotImplementedError: Wrong number r type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_group'.
>
> Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
>
> FIX::Group::Group(int, int)
>
> FIX::Group::Group(int, int, int const[])
>
> FIX::Group::Group(int, int, message_order const &)
>
> FIX::Group::Group(FIX::Group const &)

I did read the documentation and found that the Group object requires arguments
 `Group(int field, int delim)`

Not sure what to pass the values for field and delim. Appreciate your response and help.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which version of FIX you're using - 4.0, 4.2 or 4.4?
I think the problem is you are creating a base Group class in  the 'fix.Group()' call. You need to create a specific Group() object for the QuoteRequest message type. Perhaps the NoUnderlyings (Number of Underlyings) object?

Comment: Hi @JimmyNJ, I am using the version FIX1.1

Answer (score 1):

not sure I´m on time to help. But I will try. I think @JimmyNJ is giving you proper answer.

According to [official doc](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/repeating_groups.html) you can easily do it, but you don´t have to use a generic group, you have to use specific group available to your kind of message.

As far as I know, you should program something like this.

```
from quickfix44 import QuoteRequest
import quickfix as fix
message = QuoteRequest()
group = QuoteRequest.NoRelatedSym()
group.setField(fix.Symbol("GBPUSD"))
group.setField(fix.Side(fix.Side_BUY))
group.setField(fix.Account("TestAcc"))
group.setField(fix.Currency("GBP"))
message.addGroup(group)
```

I´m assuming you want to add these 4 tags into NoRelatedSym group, based in their tag numbers. I´ve also used FIX 44 version, maybe you are using a different version, but main idea is the same.